# TimeBasedRollingPolicy with no date appended

Tags: logback

I want to use a TimeBasedRollingPolicy; however, for legacy reasons (c to java port) the log file name already has a date appended, like so: "log.20130813". Other downstream processes depend on the date already being on the filename. When it rolls I want it to be compressed but with no further date appended to it. Is this possible?

I have tried this:

```
def date = timestamp("yyyyMMdd")
def logFileName = "log.${date}"

appender("LOG", RollingFileAppender) {
    file = logFileName
    append = true
    rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {      
    fileNamePattern = "${logFileName}.%d{}.gz"
}
encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%msg%n"
}
}
```

However, the empty date string just causes it to use its default so it ends up like this:

log.20130805.2013-08-05.gz

I really would like it to end up like:

log.20130805.gz

Answer (score 0):

In Curly braces. Add format like %d{yyyy-MM-dd}.

**You can also do in this manner :**
*${filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz*

Then the output would be : *filename.2013-03-15.0.log.gz*